# Pause new threads from executing using ExectuorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I would like to pause the new tasks from executing. The example provided in the [Official Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) seems to be stopping the currently executed tasks as well (though I am wondering how it does that without interrupting the thread).

```
class PausableThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
   private boolean isPaused;
   private ReentrantLock pauseLock = new ReentrantLock();
   private Condition unpaused = pauseLock.newCondition();

   public PausableThreadPoolExecutor(...) { super(...); }

   protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
     super.beforeExecute(t, r);
     pauseLock.lock();
     try {
       while (isPaused) unpaused.await();
     } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
       t.interrupt();
     } finally {
       pauseLock.unlock();
     }
   }

   public void pause() {
     pauseLock.lock();
     try {
       isPaused = true;
     } finally {
       pauseLock.unlock();
     }
   }

   public void resume() {
     pauseLock.lock();
     try {
       isPaused = false;
       unpaused.signalAll();
     } finally {
       pauseLock.unlock();
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: what's the difference between a new task and a current task?

Comment: use different executor

Comment: New Task is the one which is submitted and is in the Queue. The current task is the one which is being executed (but is not yet finished).

Comment: if you don't want a task to execute - just don't submit it to a thread pool. Save in an intermediate collection, and then pass to the thread pool when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was incorrect. The PausablableThreadPoolExecutor does not stop the currently executed thread. Apologies for the incorrect question.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the Runnable interface could be easier for this, then you don't have to make your own ThreadPool.

```
public abstract class PausableRunnable implements Runnable{
     private final object _monitor;
     public PausableRunnable(object monitor){
         _monitor = monitor;
     }
     @Override
     public void Run(){
         WaitForNotify();
     }

     public void WaitForNotify(){
         synchronized(_monitor){
             while(!done){
                 _monitor.wait();
             }
         }
         doWork();
     }
     public abstract void doWork();
}
```

This could pause new threads easily.  Pausing a running thread is a different task, I think this is what you meant.  The biggest problem with my solution is if you already want to inherit from something, but it's a starting point